# Node: Passing function to a Promise

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm new to Node and have never done much with front-end web development or Javascript, but I am trying to do a couple simple front-end tasks and am seeing errors I don't understand. I've read a number of post on the errors I'm seeing, but many do not have accepted answers, and others seem unrelated. I have also read through the section on promises a couple times in the Node.js Web Development book by David Herron, so I think I understand the ideas behind promises, but I am getting confused by some of the errors I am seeing.

I am running an express.js server. I have one query method in a file query.js which (simplified) takes a key and returns a value and looks like this:

```
'use strict'
function query(key) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        // ... lots of stuff and more '.then' things
    }).then((arg) => {
        return arg[0] // this is always a string
    }
module.export.query = query
```

I then have a server.js file, which contains the code for the express server.
One way works and one way doesn't, and I can't figure out what the difference is. Here's the way that works as expected:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
var q = require('./query.js')

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

app.post('/path', function (req, res) {
    q.query(req.body.param).then(console.log).catch((err) => {
        console.error("My Error:", err)
    }
    res.send("arbitrary string")
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

When I send the post request, with param='key' it correctly outputs 'value' to the console and sends "arbitrary string" back to the client. but, if I try to put res.send as the argument to the '.then' thing in order to return the retrieved value to the client, I get an error. So if I change the app.post to:

```
app.post('/path', function (req, res) {
    q.query(req.body.param).then(res.send).catch((err) => {
        console.error("My Error:", err)
    }
})
```

I get

```
My Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
    at send (/home/u/NodeServer/node/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:110:17)
```

Does anyone know why one console.log (which takes a string as an argument) will work when res.send (which also takes a string as an argument) will not?  I find this very strange, especially since res.send works only outside of the promise structure, and console.log works everywhere.

Comment: what got exactly in line 110:17

Comment: Hint: the issue relates to `this`. You are passing the method, but you lose the object the method is to be applied on. Use a function in which you call `res.send`, or use `apply`.

Comment: Drilling into the express.js libraries it is at the top of the definition of res.send (res.send = function send(body) { var chunk = body; var encoding; var req = this.req; ...

Comment: What does the promise that `q.query(req.body.param)` returns resolved to?  What type of value?  Object?  String?  Number?  Because if it's an object that you want to send back to your client, then `q.query(req.body.param).then(res.send.bind(res))` should work.

Comment: @jfriend00 the promise should always resolve to a string.

Comment: @jcaron I just tried to read quickly on "apply" and tried running <code>q.query(req.body.param).then(res.send.apply(req)</code> and got a new error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fresh' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.send (/home/u/NodeServer/node/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:206:10)"

Comment: You should pass `res`, not `req`, since that is the object you want to call the method on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a binding problem. Writing `res.send` like that will detach the function from `res`. Try this to retain the binding:

```
res.send.bind(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I replaced then(res.send) with then(res.send.bind(res)) and am still getting the same error.

Comment: This answer is definitely at least part of the problem.  In other words, this does have to be fixed the way it is described here.  It may not be the entire problem and it may not be the first thing wrong leading to the error you get, but this is a fix that needs to be applied.

Comment: I tweaked something else in my testing that I forgot to undo when running the test, but upon undoing and making the change, your answer is correct. Thank you very much!